# $args->has_children not working with start_el()

Tags: walker

Why $has_children doesn't work here?

```
class walker_name extends Walker_Nav_Menu{
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
            $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
            $class_names = $value = '';
            $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
            $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
            $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';
            $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';
            $attributes = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="' . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
            $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target ) ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target ) .'"' : '';
            $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn ) ? ' rel="' . esc_attr( $item->xfn ) .'"' : '';
            $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url ) ? ' href="' . esc_attr( $item->url ) .'"' : '';

            $item_output = $args->before;
            $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
            $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
            $item_output .= '</a>';
            $has_children = (is_object($args) && $args->has_children) || (is_array($args) && $args['has_children']);
            if ( $has_children ) {
                // not working
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I'm experiencing the same problem. Using var_dump it even shows that $args has this value and it is even set correctly, but when i try to get this value I get nothing instead.

Answer (score 5):

I just resolved this issue! Woo hoo! The thing is that using `var_dump($args)` shows a lot stuff like so:

```
object(stdClass)#152 (16) { ["menu"]=> object(WP_Term)#145 (10) { ["term_id"]=>
int(2) ["name"]=> string(9) "Main menu" ["slug"]=> string(9) "main-menu"
["term_group"]=> int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(2) ["taxonomy"]=> string(8)
"nav_menu" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> int(0) ["count"]=> int(12)
["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } ["container"]=> string(0) "" ["container_class"]=>
string(0) "" ["container_id"]=> string(0) "" ["menu_class"]=> string(4) "menu"
["menu_id"]=> string(0) "" ["echo"]=> bool(true) ["fallback_cb"]=> string(12)
"wp_page_menu" ["before"]=> string(0) "" ["after"]=> string(0) "" ["link_before"]=>
string(0) "" ["link_after"]=> string(0) "" ["items_wrap"]=> string(4) "%3$s"
["depth"]=> int(0) ["walker"]=> object(themeslug_walker_nav_menu)#151 (4) {
["tree_type"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(9) "post_type" [1]=> string(8) "taxonomy"
[2]=> string(6) "custom" } ["db_fields"]=> array(2) { ["parent"]=> string(16)
"menu_item_parent" ["id"]=> string(5) "db_id" } ["max_pages"]=> int(1)
["has_children"]=> bool(true) } ["theme_location"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Searching through this dump you can clearly see `["has_children"]=> bool(true)` but the thing is that it isn't part of `$args` object! In fact it is part of object which is held under `"walker"` value. This is more obvious when you indent a bit output like so:

```
object(stdClass)#152 (16) {
    ["menu"]=> object(WP_Term)#145 (10) {
        ["term_id"]=> int(2)
        ["name"]=> string(9) "Main menu"
        ["slug"]=> string(9) "main-menu"
        ["term_group"]=> int(0)
        ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(2)
        ["taxonomy"]=> string(8) "nav_menu"
        ["description"]=> string(0) ""
        ["parent"]=> int(0)
        ["count"]=> int(12)
        ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw"
    }
    ["container"]=> string(0) ""
    ["container_class"]=> string(0) ""
    ["container_id"]=> string(0) ""
    ["menu_class"]=> string(4) "menu"
    ["menu_id"]=> string(0) ""
    ["echo"]=> bool(true)
    ["fallback_cb"]=> string(12) "wp_page_menu"
    ["before"]=> string(0) ""
    ["after"]=> string(0) ""
    ["link_before"]=> string(0) ""
    ["link_after"]=> string(0) ""
    ["items_wrap"]=> string(4) "%3$s"
    ["depth"]=> int(0)
    ["walker"]=> object(themeslug_walker_nav_menu)#151 (4) {
        ["tree_type"]=> array(3) {
            [0]=> string(9) "post_type"
            [1]=> string(8) "taxonomy"
            [2]=> string(6) "custom"
        }
        ["db_fields"]=> array(2) {
            ["parent"]=> string(16) "menu_item_parent"
            ["id"]=> string(5) "db_id"
        }
        ["max_pages"]=> int(1)
        ["has_children"]=> bool(true)
    }
    ["theme_location"]=> string(0) ""
}
```

Now you can clearly see that to access `has_children` property you need to call this line:

```
$args->walker->has_children
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you think that `$args->has_children` (or `$args['has_children']`) exists at all. I am not finding that in my tests [nor do I see it in source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src//wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L0).

I think that what you want is `$menu_item->menu_item_parent` as [seen in the Core walker](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src//wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L330).

```
330         $sorted_menu_items = $menu_items_with_children = array();
331         foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $menu_item ) {
332                 $sorted_menu_items[ $menu_item->menu_order ] = $menu_item;
333                 if ( $menu_item->menu_item_parent )
334                         $menu_items_with_children[ $menu_item->menu_item_parent ] = true;
335         }
```